# Avoid returning 'false' from an empty UTM value in a URL

Tags: jquery, url, uri

I'm trying to add strings passed via a url UTM code. My issue is whenever a UTM value is empty the word 'false' appears on the front end.

I'm guessing I need to say `if UTM is empty/false then display nothing` I'm not sure how to do this with jQuery - how would I modify the following code?

Here's a [live example of the problem](https://jubileetalent.com/apply/?title=SOUS%20CHEF%20%E2%80%93%2026K%20PACKAGE%20%E2%80%93%20BUSY%20FRESH%20FOOD%20RESTAURANT%20%E2%80%93%20PAID%20OVERTIME&email=ollie.tobias%40jubileetalent.com&job=OTPU%205859)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
     }
   return(false);
  }

  var title = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable('title'));
  var subtitle = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable('subtitle'));


  $('.headline').removeClass('h1').addClass('h5 ntm');
  $('.headline').append('<br><span class="h1 job-title ntm nbm">' + title + '</span><span class="h3 job-subtitle ntm nbm">' + subtitle + '</span>');


});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

Much of the time it would be `var subtitle` that is empty.

(`var title` would almost always have a value)

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional

```
var title = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable('title'));
var subtitle = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable('subtitle'));

if(title && subtitle ){  

  $('.headline').removeClass('h1').addClass('h5 ntm');
  $('.headline').append('<br><span class="h1 job-title ntm nbm">' + title + '</span><span class="h3 job-subtitle ntm nbm">' + subtitle + '</span>');

}
```

Comment: Thank you, no joy I'm afraid - If this helps, `var title = ...` would always have a value. `var subtitle = ...` is the one that would be empty on occasion

Comment: so what behavior do you want if one of them exists?

Comment: It more of a case if one of them does not exist - currently the word 'false' appears if `var subtitle` is empty. I'd just like it to display nothing at all if this is the case.

Comment: can do something like: `var subtitle = decodeURIComponent(getQueryVariable('subtitle')) || '';` . Will make the value an empty string if it is false. Otherwise if you don't want that element to exist will need to piece together the html string using conditionals

Comment: Thank you - it still displays as 'false' - what I have noticed is the if a subtitle has not been set then this part of the UTM (`&email=`) is not created at all

Answer (score 0):

Came back to this...

Need to wrap in a 'if is not fase' conditional

```
if (subtitle !== 'false') {
  // Stuff
}
```